# Project keep asking for old version of DLL even after providing more latest version

Tags: c#, dll, version

I have this tricky problem eating my mind from past 2 days.. Please note that I'm slightly out of data with DotNet & C# projects..

I have a ASP.NET web site which has a reference to a library say X with version number 7.0, Note that this library is referenced from a fixed folder in the solution (no nuget). Now, I had to do some modifications to this library and luckily I have the source code of Next version of it and so I have modified and copied the 8.0 library in to the same folder and added to reference it again.

First of all, Is that the right way of doing it if I have to upgrade?  If yes, Then why my project is showing 500+ errors saying missing reference to V7.0 library ?

FYI, this library brings in a couple more as well as dependencies, So I have upgraded them as well.

Any suggestions would be greatly helpful.

Thank you
-Srikanth

Comment: Check the timestamp of dll file in project bin folder.  The new dll should automatically get copied in to the project bi folder.

Comment: @jdweng, the bin folder at the moment is empty , I'm not able to build it self with all these 100s of errors asking for old version of libraries..

Comment: First you  should remove old library suing Solution Explorer : References : Right click the reference and remove.  The from menu : Project :  Add Reference and Browse to location where dll is located.  Then do a clean build (or delete the obj folder from the project).  Everything should then get recompiled with correct version of library.

Comment: Glad to hear that @jdweng. I did exactly the same thing and still it is not working. I was wondering till now if it is something I'm missing till now. The project has lot of other libraries referenced along with this one. Could there be any possibility of having version compatibility but the error is showing for this library instead of others?

Comment: The error should contain the folder of source file(s).